# Unusual behavior with or operator in vimrc

Tags: vim, grep

I usually do a search and replace in vim that looks like this:

```
:%s/\([\.!?]\|[\.!?]"\)\s\s/\1text /g
```

So it looks for either a period, exclamation point, question mark, or any of the above followed by a quote and two spaces.  It works fine.

But when I map this in my vimrc like so

```
map <F4> :%s/\([\.!?]\|[\.!?]"\)\s\s/\1text /g<CR>
```

and then press F4 I get this error message:

```
E486: Pattern not found: \([\.!?]|[\.!?]"\)\s\s
```

It is removing the backslash before the pipe for some reason and I have no idea why.  Does anyone know how to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `:map`ping, the pipe character is special. Use `<Bar>` instead:

```
:noremap <F4> :%s/\([\.!?]\<Bar>[\.!?]"\)\s\s/\1text /g<CR>
```

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the info on recursion too.  Helped me clean up the vimrc file.

Comment: Lets clean up that regex! The matching group does not need alternation (the `\|`) instead you can get by with `\=`. `\=` matches 0 or 1 times, as many as possible (think Perl's `?`). That makes the substitution: `%s/\([\.!?]"\=\)\s\s/\1text /g`. Because we are not using the pipe symbol the `<bar>` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, the obvious answer always escapes me.